# Laravel User Post Image

Tags: image, laravel, post, upload

This is in user controller

```
  public function store(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            'body' => 'required'
        ]);


        if( $request->hasFile('image') ) {
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            Image::make($image)->resize(600, 600)->save( public_path('uploads/images/' . $filename ) );
        }

        $post = Post::get();
        $post->image = $filename;
        $post->save();

         Session::flash( 'sucess', 'Post published.' );

        auth()->user()->publish(
            new Post(request(['body']))
        );

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

I am unable to post an Image seeing some alternate errors SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:

> 1364 Field 'image' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into
>   `posts` (`body`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (dddd, 2018-02-21
>   09:42:49, 2018-02-21 09:42:49))

Comment: dd($filename) it's probably null;

Comment: Can you show your `publish` method?

Comment: `public function publish(Post $post)
    {
        $this->posts()->save($post);
    }`

Comment: still has same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because $image is null and it's column in DB is not nullable, make it nullable

```
$table->string('image')->nullable();
```

or don't pass null

```
$post->image = $filename ?? '';//this is php 7 syntax
```

or

```
 $post->image = isset($filename) ? $filename :' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the field is not nullable, you should change the code to:

```
$post->image = $filename ?? '';
```

Or make the `image` field `nullable` in related migration file:

```
$table->string('image')->nullable();
```

Also, instead of `get()`:

```
$post = Post::get();
```

You should just create a new `Post` instance:

```
$post = new Post;
```